# can I pass an argument to a virtual schema populate in mongoose 5.7.12?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I want to pass an argument to the virtual populate a define in my schema to match a query based on the argument passed, my current code is :

```
PostSchema.virtual('liked_by_me',{
    ref:'likes',
    localField:'likes',
    foreignField:'_id',
    justOne:false,
    count: true,
})
```

and I am calling it from my controller :

```
PostModel.find().limit(limit).
    skip(page*limit).
        sort(
        {created_at:-1}
    )
        .populate('created_by_user','nickname -_id')
        .populate('likes_count')
        .populate({
        path:'liked_by_me',
        match: { user: req.user._id },
        count: true
    }).exec()
```

but instead is there a way to pass the user_id to the liked_by_me populate and query based on the 
user id inside the schema?.